Language selection in multi-brand stores each with multi storeviews
I'm hoping someone can help us with the following.
We are using Magento 2 and have 4 brand stores in it, each with a separate URL. Each brand store has 3 storeviews for English, German and Dutch. We have a language switch installed, but the domain currently remains the main domain without adding the language to it. This provides problems in marketing (using links) and for SEO. So I would like to find a way to add the language to the domain.
Example:
www.brand1.com = main domain
www.brand1.com/nl = language variant for Dutch
www.brand1.com/de = language variant for German
www.brand1.com/en = language variant for English
However, my developer says this is not possible because we can only use the exact language code in URL once for our whole account. And since we have 4 brands in the account, I don't know how to solve this issue.
Can anyone help us?

We have worked with different languages on the same domain as you intend to do without any issues. The main problem seems to be the language switcher, which is designed without your desired setup in mind.
One option should be to review the module, find where they determine the postfix or code url, and create a new module to overwrite that behavior.
Without further info on the language switcher is not possible for further details on this.
The other option is to look for a language switcher that support different urls.
Does the default language switcher that comes with Magento does not work out of the box in your case?

Hi, the language switcher itself works, but the language does not appear in the URL which leads to some caching issues and other problems in loading pages per language. We would like to know how we can get the language in the url?

Usually we used www.mydomain.com/en/ as the base url for the storeview and use /spa/ for the other storeview and that was enough.... You might need to fiddle afterwards with the basic link and assets urls if you have issues, but that depends on how complex your configuration is

From my experience, this isn’t really an issue at all. The store code will be based on the URL, and the most optimized setup, in my opinion, is having one website per currency. Then, you can have one store per language under each website, and make sure the shipping countries are split across those stores, so no country overlaps between stores. It might seem counterintuitive at first, but in the end, it gives customers a clearer experience where each country has a single currency. Plus, it makes managing shipping methods way less of a headache.

Hi, we don't have the issue of currencies since we only sell in Euros. But I need the language code to be shown in the URL and we don't know how to do this??? Please help

You just need to have one website, and in the unique website one store per language, with the language code being the store's code. That's it !
